# Attempting to bridge Discord messages to Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, discord.py, python-telegram-bot

Need a bit of help, trying to create a bridge between a discord channel & a telegram channel. Ive gotten messages from Discord sending to the Telegram but i am stumped on getting the telegram messages sent to the Discord. I'm getting the Telegram messages but i can't figure out how to pass them on to the Discord.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import telegram.ext
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters, Updater

telegram_token = 'str'
telegram_group = 'str'
discord_channel = 'int'


class repeater(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        homechannel = self.bot.get_channel(discord_channel)
        if message.channel == homechannel:
            Tele_Bot = telegram.Bot(token=telegram_token)
            Tele_Bot.sendMessage(chat_id=telegram_group, text=f'{message.guild.name}:{message.author}:\n{message.content}')
            print('Message Detected from Discord & Sent')


class telegram_repeater(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    updater = Updater(token=telegram_token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    def echo(update, context):
        #The Magic would Happen here.

    echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo)
    dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)
    updater.start_polling()


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(repeater(bot))
    bot.add_cog(telegram_repeater(bot))
```

How can i get a discord channel and then send the telegram message to it?

Comment: use an async telegram library if you don't want to face any big issues when dealing with async to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already imported discord and ran the client bot:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.run('your token here')
```

Sending a message to a specific channel:

```py
channel = client.get_channel(discord_channel_id)
await channel.send_message(your_message_string)
```

#### Links you should take a look at

- [discord.py api reference: Quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
- [discord.py api reference: How do I send a message to a specific channel?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)